# Want to ask why there appear an error in L.append

Tags: python

I am self-learning python recently, I have the solution but I just want to know why the L.appendix have error here

```
Given a list of number i.e. [1,2,3,-5,7,9,3,2],
make another list that contains all the items sorted from min to max
```

```
L=[1,2,4,-5,7,9,3,2]
M=[]
minv=L[0]
while not(len(L)==0):
    for i in L:
        if i<=minv:
            minv=i
    M.append(minv)    
    L.remove(minv)
```

list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: As soon as you meet the min value in `L` (in your case -5), `minv` will stay -5 forever. You need to set `minv=L[0]` inside `while` loop.

Comment: Also not to mention, that your problem can be easily solved with `L.sort()`

Comment: I'm curious what you were thinking when writing `not(len(L)==0)` instead of `len(L) != 0` or `len(L)` or - the most pythonic option - just `while L:` ;)

Comment: Oh, these seem much better, but I haven't learned about these before, so 0 and[] can be used as False too?

Comment: See the documentation for boolean expressions: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations TLDR: False, None, zero, empty strings, and empty lists all evaluate to False and anything else evaluates to True

Answer (score 0):

L.sort() will sort the list in-place, which might work but is different than what your instructions indicated.  If you want another list in proper order while leaving L unchanged, use the built-in sorted() function:

```
M = sorted(L)
```